# Do i have to configure the VLAN on my switch if its already configured in the firewall

Tags: vlan, fortinet

i have fortinet 51E firewall from the firewall GUI there is an option to configure a VLAN , my question is if i configured the VLAN in the firewall do i need to configure it again in the switch?

Comment: Depends on your network design. If you only have one VLAN on the firewall and no configuration on your switches, it will probably work without problems.

Comment: the network in my company contains only one switch and firewall(fortinet) and 5 access points, What i want to do is to create tow VLANs one for the printers which have static IPs and the other one for the PC's.
for this network is it enough to just create the VLANs from the firewall side or i have to connect to the switch and create the VLANs there for each access point.

Comment: Can you post your switch configuration?

Comment: Unfortunately i can't, just to let you know i'm still new in the company and this is the first time i'm working with fortinet firewall, what i know is that the VALNs are configured on the switch level so what i'm planning to do is to access the switch configure VLAN for the laptops in my company allowing required IP's/Ports, then configure another VLAN for the printer which has static IP's and allow only the printer IP's and ports.
Please Advise if this approach is correct and will not cause any impact to my internal LAN and if there any thing i need to do from the firewall side.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VLAN tagging is used to pass multiple, distinct segments on a single, physical link (a *VLAN trunk*).

If your network is using multiple segments and you want them to connect to the firewall directly, you can use a VLAN trunk between firewall and switch. The trunk must be set up in the exact same way on both ends.

If there's only one LAN segment connecting to the firewall there's no point in setting up VLAN tagging.

*edit after comment:*

> the network in my company contains only one switch and firewall(fortinet) and 5 access points, What i want to do is to create tow VLANs one for the printers which have static IPs and the other one for the PC's. for this network is it enough to just create the VLANs from the firewall side or i have to connect to the switch and create the VLANs there for each access point.

For this you can use VLAN tagging.

If you add a VLAN on the switch, configure the printer ports for that VLAN as untagged, and configure the firewall link as tagged, you can add the VLAN as tagged subinterface on the Fortigate. Set up policies for clients accessing the printers and you should be set (I'm assuming the clients use the Fortigate as default gateway anyway).

You can do the same for the wireless APs (or use one common VLAN for all WAPs), but as long as your client subnet isn't getting too crowded this just complicates matters.

Comment: Thank you very much, This is very helpful and yes you are right the default gateway for the clients is the Fortigate.